# Where is read_mailbox (Facebook API)

Tags: php, facebook

I have used `('GET', 'me/inbox')` to get my inbox messages by php for about 2-month.
But it seems to fail now.
So, I checked the permission on Graph API explorer, and found that `"read_mailbox"` is not on the list.
Where is `read_mailbox` ?

The second question:
I tried to use `"read_page_mailbox"` to achieve the some goal but I don't know how to get conversation-id.
Can someone help me or give me examples for `read_page_mailbox` ?

==UPDATE==

Here is my code.

```
session_start();

define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', 'facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/');
require __DIR__ . '/facebook/php-sdk-v4/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id , $app_secret);
$session = new FacebookSession($token);

$user_inbox = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/inbox'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
print_r($user_inbox);
```

And I tried to follow this page to use `read_page_mailbox`.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/conversation
How to get the `conversation-id` ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using?

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: Conversations a page is involved in can be read via the [`/{page-id}/conversations`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/conversations/) endpoint.

Comment: If you want to read the conversations a certain page has with its users, then you should _have_ the page id already, no? // It seems that you might need to be more clear about what you are actually trying to _achieve_ here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

> The /v2.4/{user_id}/home, /v2.4/{user_id}/inbox, and /v2.4/{user_id}/notifications edges as well as read_stream, **read_mailbox**, and manage_notifications permissions are **deprecated** in v2.4.

Comment: Will it be possible to access inbox in some other way from now on?

Comment: No. That's no longer possible.

Comment: Looks like I'm late to the party. I just wanted to create an app that exports my personal chat history. Is this use case no longer supported?

Comment: If no... is there another way to make lengthy conversations more manageable (100k+ messages)? The provided search tools do a poor job at filtering long conversations, taking up to minutes for simple searches.

Comment: Most important of all, the search tools do not provide an option to scroll back to messages of a specific date.

Comment: @StevenLiekens use v2.3 (until July 8, 2017)

Comment: @StevenLiekens I can get it using the Graph API Explorer

Comment: Then it must be impossible for new users to get access, because I can't @suriv

Comment: An app is always tied to the most recent version of the Graph API to the date the app was created. So, if your app was created when v2.4 was already in place, you can't go back to v2.3. There's no way to avoid this.

Comment: Not even with sandbox keys that work only for yourself?

Comment: Pretty poor that they removed this :( I'm trying to create an autoresponder for my personal profile (not page) messenger. Anyone found any workarounds?

Comment: @JoelMurphy the only workaround I see would be using web scraping, with a Greasemonkey script or something like a Selenium WebDriver script. I wanted to do this to send and receive Facebook messages using SMS (with a second phone number connected to Internet on my home network).